# Vue - is it possible to pass in a data property into a method to be modified?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that displays balances for 4 separate tokens. I'd like to have a function like this:

```
    async updateTokenBalance(token, balance) {
      balance = await getTokenBalance(token);
      balance = balance.value.uiAmount;
    }
```

which I can call like so:

```
updateTokenBalance(this.a_acc, this.a_balance);
updateTokenBalance(this.b_acc, this.b_balance);
updateTokenBalance(this.c_acc, this.c_balance);
updateTokenBalance(this.d_acc, this.d_balance);
```

unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The only way I've gotten it to work so far is by having 4 separate functions:

```
    async updateATokenBalance() {
      let balance = await getTokenBalance(this.a_acc);
      this.a_balance = balance.value.uiAmount;
    }
    // the other 3 analogous
```

in particular, it's the second line of the function where I try to assign the balance to a data property of `this.a_balance` that breaks if `this.a_balance` is passed in as arg.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If your data come from an API, you should iterate through the incoming object list and run the function for each item with the analogous arguments.